# Background color change onclick refactoring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to JQuery/JavaScript.

I have successfully got the toggle to work on the am/pm buttons you may view it here: 
[Working Code](http://codepen.io/Lgalan90/pen/wKdVwq)

I am now trying to refactor my code using "this". I haven't figured out whats wrong with using if statements to change the background. Please view here: 
[Code I'm refactoring](http://codepen.io/Lgalan90/pen/yYprXV)

```
$('.ampm').click(function() {
console.log($(this).attr('id'));

var text = $(this).text();
$('#meridiem').val(text);

if ($(this).attr('id') === $('#am')) {
$('#wrapper').css('background-color', 'orange');
} else if ($(this).attr('id') === $('#pm')) {
$('#wrapper').css('background-color', 'blue');
}
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you test `.attr('id')`, don't use the # in the string.  Also, when you are comparing it, just use `'am'` and `'pm'` instead of wrapping it as a jQuery object.  Lastly, when setting CSS with JavaScript/jQuery, use the `backgroundColor` syntax instead of `background-color`.

```
$('.ampm').click(function() {

  var text = $(this).text();
  $('#meridiem').val(text);

  if ($(this).attr('id') === 'am') {
console.log('am');
    $('#wrapper').css('backgroundColor', 'orange');
  } else if ($(this).attr('id') === 'pm') {
    $('#wrapper').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');
  }
});
```

Comment: Very helpful Tony Hinkle and BG101! I wasn't aware that after using .attr('id') I could call each ID directly by its name.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this:-

```
if ($(this).attr('id') === $('#am')) {
```

to this:-

```
if ($(this).attr('id') === 'am') {
```

and the same for your `else if`

you were comparing a string to a jquery object